# How to fix "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance"?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios13

I am creating a new app, and need help with getting my Core Data entity to update a field when the corresponding tableView cell is clicked.

I have tried Googling the error and similar errors but everything I could find was in Objective-c or an older version of swift.  I am using swift. I am also using the NSFetchedResultsController to fetch data.

This is my tableView's did selectRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = fetchedRC.object(at:indexPath)

    /*if item.isComplete {
        item.setValue(false, forKey: "isComplete")
        //item.isComplete = false
    } else {
        item.setValue(true, forKey: "isComplete")
        //item.isComplete = true
    }*/

    item.isComplete.toggle()

    do {
        try context.save()
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on the cell I want the `IsComplete` to switch its value according to if it is true or false.  But instead what it actually does is crash when is calls the 'setValue' in both cases of the if statement.  The error message is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x9321d02e963b75fc'

EDIT:
I believe this is where the declaration of isComplete would be

```
extension Item {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var list: List?

}
```

And the DidSet:

```
var detailedList: List! {
    didSet {

   }
}
```

Request and Sort

```
let request = Item.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Item>
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", parentObj)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.isComplete), ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
        fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try fetchedRC.performFetch()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    fetchedRC.delegate = self
```

Comment: The error states that somewhere the value of `isComplete` is treated as a string. By the way why not `item.isComplete = true` (rather than KVC) or even simply `item.isComplete.toggle()` replacing the entire `if - else` expression.

Comment: Ok and I did not even know you could just toggle the value, but that unfortunately did not fix the problem.  It still crashes with the same error.

Comment: How is `isCompleted` declared? If the error is still occurring then the mistake is in the class

Comment: `isCompleted` is declared as a boolean.  Where might the mistake be in the class?

Comment: I don't know. Is there any code executed in the class when the property is set for example a `didSet` observer? Is `caseInsensitiveCompare` called somewhere in reality? It could also be used implicitly in `sort` and `filter` operations.

Comment: I have a `didSet` and I have a `NSSortDescriptor`. Do I need to add that code to the question?

Comment: Is the Exception Breakpoint set? If not set it. It gives you the stack trace and more detailed information about the location of the crash. Yes, add the declation of `isComplete`

Comment: I do not think so no.  Though I am not totally sure what that is or where that would be either.

Comment: Press ⌘8, click the + sign bottom left and choose Exception Breakpoint. Learn and get used to use the Debugger. It's a very powerful tool.

Comment: Ok I turned on the Exception Breakpoint and added more of the code above.  The Exception Breakpoint also highlighted the `try context.save()` when I ran it again and tried selecting a cell.

Comment: Press the Continue button in the debug area when the crash occurs and read the stack trace. The first enabled line is the actual place where the crash occurs.

Comment: Ok where or what do I need to be looking for in the stack trace then?  What do you mean by an enabled line?  Is that what it highlighted or the first line that my project comes up in the stack trace?

Comment: In the navigation bar there are the threads and in the debug area is a popup menu to select them. I recommend to read or watch some tutorials about `Debugging in Xcode` to learn the basics. It's worth it.

Comment: I will have to watch some at some point then too.  And I think I might have found where it is pointing to, in the stack trace there is a line that is pointing to my `controllerWillChangeContent` in my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` extension.  Could this be it?

Comment: Yes, could be, somewhere must be a line where `isCompleted` is involved in a wrong way. You can also search with ⇧⌘F for all occurrences of `isComplete`

Comment: I am sorry, I do not think that is actually where it is because I just realized I do not call `isComplete` in there, but I think upon further inspection and looking at some Debugging Tutorials that it may be in my `viewDidLoad`.  Specifically it could be the line involving the `NSSortDescriptor` because the `NSSortDescriptor` takes a String.  And I searched all in the file and only have three occurrences.  Once in my `NSSortDescriptor`, then once in my `cellForRow`, and then once in my `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: That is where it is, changing the sort from `isComplete` to my name field stopped the crashing, but then as expected does not sort how indented.

Comment: As I said in my second comment *...could also be used implicitly in **sort** and filter operations*. For the Bool value you have to write a custom sort descriptor for example with the `comparator` parameter.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I did not realize that is want you meant.  Ok thank you, and thank you for being willing to help.  I will try using a custom sort descriptor then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you cannot sort `Bool` values with the `caseInsensitiveCompare` selector.

Just use the standard descriptor

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.isComplete), ascending: true)
```

Comment: Ok.  I created this and this works find: `let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isComplete", ascending: true)`  which would be better to use?

Comment: The literal string works, but syntax which is checked at compile time is safer. However the `#keyPath` syntax should work. too.

Comment: So would it be better to use what you gave?  Or would just doing `let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Item.isComplete), ascending: true)` be fine too?

Comment: Your fine, thank you for helping fine the solution!  I am not sure if this would need to be asked in a new question or not but how would I go about calling this again or moving the selected cell to where it is supposed to be according to the sort?

Comment: That's a new question.

Comment: Ok. I figured it would be.